# Google cloud function & Imagemagick: can't deal with PDF

Tags: firebase, imagemagick, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions

I am trying to convert the first page of a pdf uploaded to Storage to a JPG so that I can generate a thumbnail and display it to my users. I use Imagemagick for that. The issue is that it seems like Google cloud function instances don't have ghostscript (gs) that seems to be a dependency to manipulate pdfs.

Is there a way to have it available in some way?

(fyi, I am able to properly convert on my local machine with both Imagemagick and ghostscript installed). So, I know the command I am using is good.

AWS Lambda instances have ghostscript installed by the way

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Actually Ghostscript was deprecated from the app engine as well. I think your best option is maybe to use [pdf.js](https://github.com/mozilla/pdf.js/) deployed with your cloud function. I have not tried it myself but it looks like the only way forward with the current state of CF. Other option is to deploy a GCE with Ghostscript and send a request from the CF to convert the PDF page for you.